# What's the equivalent of .get in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python

```
d = {'hello':'abc'}
d.get('hello','default_val');
```

Above is python.  How to do this in javascript? I want to be able to set a default value if no key found.

Comment: try with the answers given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have (at least) four/five options:

1. In modern environments, you'd probably use the [nullish coalescing operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) (`??`):

   ```
   x = obj.key ?? "default";
   ```

   If `obj.key` results in `undefined` or `null`, `"default"` is used instead; if `obj.key` results in for any other value, that value is used (including various falsy values like `""`).

   In obsolete environments that don't have `??`, you can use [the curiously-powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html):

   ```
   x = obj.key || "default";
   ```

   If `obj.key` results in *any [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value* (including `""`), that will use `"default"` instead; otherwise, it'll use the value. Where you can, you'll generally want to use `??` instead of `||` because it more accurately tests for a "missing" value.
2. This is now obsolete, `??` handles this case. <s>For situations where `||` isn't applicable, there's the `in` operator:</s>

   ```
   x = "key" in obj ? obj.key : "default";
   ```

   `in` tells us whether an object has a property with the given key. Note the key is a string (property names are strings or Symbols; if you were using a Symbol, you'd know). So if `obj.key` may be validly `0`, you'd want to use this rather than #1 above.
3. `in` (and `obj.key`) will find a key if it's in the object *or* the object's prototype chain. If you just want to check the object itself and not its prototype chain, in modern environments you can use `Object.hasOwn`:

   ```
   x = Object.hasOwn(obj, "key") ? obj.key : "default";
   ```

   In obsolete environments without `hasOwn`, you can use a polyfill, or use `hasOwnProperty` (but beware the object can have its own version of `hasOwnProperty` that may not tell the truth):

   ```
   x = obj.hasOwnProperty("key") ? obj.key : "default";
   ```
4. If you don't want to exclude `null`, you can specifically check for `undefined`:

   ```
   x = typeof obj.key !== "undefined" ? obj.key : "default";
   ```

   That will use the default if `obj` doesn't have that property **or** if it has the property, but the property's value is `undefined`.

Comment: Wow, never knew this. Does this work in other languages too (especially PHP)? It's really great.

Comment: @Tim: I don't know PHP well enough to answer that. In most languages (C, C++, C#, Java), `||` just returns `true` or `false`. JavaScript's version is more interesting and more in the "functional" style of programming. (BTW, `&&` does something similar: It gives you the thing on the right if the thing on the left is "truthy", or `false` if it isn't.)

Comment: @TJCrowder, I just tested it and it doesn't work in PHP :( ... Thanks anyway =)!

Comment: @Tim: [apparently not in PHP](http://ideone.com/TNS1O) but it does in [Perl](http://ideone.com/HDywK) and [Ruby](http://ideone.com/ktbkW).

Answer (score 5):

Javascript's [logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) is [short-circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). You can do:

```
d["hello"] || "default_val";
```

Comment: This is potentially misleading - if the value is falsy, the OR will trigger.

Answer (score 2):

Using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Default_values_2):

```js
const { hello = 'default_val' } = d
```

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
var d = {'hello':'abc'};
var helloVar = d.hello ? d.hello : 'default_val';
```

Comment: FWIW, that will work exactly like `helloVar = d.hello || 'default_val';`

Comment: Yep, though `... || ...` is much shorter and more readable. Too bad it doesn't work in other languages, it would definitely made my day :p!